# How to prevent refreshing page after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this `php` page with `javascript ajax` which calls another `php` file. But every time it calls, it refreshes the page.

I tried these two codes but still it keeps refreshing after calling the `php file:

```
  e.preventDefault(); 
  //and   
  return false;
```

But still it keeps redirecting/refreshing to the same page. **I don't even have redirecting headers in php file I'm calling.**

This is my `HTML`

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 ad-image">
                        <label for="file1">
                            <img id="blah1" src="http://placehold.it/500" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
                            <input type="button" value="Remove Photo" style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="image-remove-btn-1">
                            <small id="textCount" class="form-text text-center bold">Thumbnail</small>
                        </label>
      </div>
```

Here's my `javascript`

```
       $("#image-remove-btn-1").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //doesn't work still page keeps refreshing

            $('#blah1').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/500');

            var userId =<?php echo $userId ?>;
            var adId =<?php echo $adId ?>;

            deletePhoto('blah1', userId, adId); //this is the function with ajax               
            $(this).hide();

            return false; //doesn't work still page keeps refreshing
        });
```

Here's the `deletePhoto()` function:

```
        function deletePhoto(imgeName, userid, adId) {
            $(document).ready(function () {                                      
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'includes/remove-ad-image-inc.php',
                    dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything                        
                    data: {
                        userId: userid,
                        adId: adId,
                        imgeName: imgeName
                    },
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (php_script_response) {
                        alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
                    }

                });

            });                               
        }
```

This is my php `remove-ad-image-inc.php` I am calling through above `ajax`

```
<?php

include_once './dbConnection.php';

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();
}

 $userId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, filter_input(INPUT_POST, "userId"));
$adId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, filter_input(INPUT_POST, "adId"));
$imgeName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, filter_input(INPUT_POST, "imgeName"));



if (isset($userId) && isset($adId) && isset($imgeName)) {


$sql = "SELECT * FROM adimage WHERE adimageno=? AND adid=? AND userid=?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "error!";
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sii", $imgeName, $adId, $userId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $ImageId = $row['adimageid'];

    }


    $fileName = "../uploads/ad/adImage-" . $ImageId . "-" . $adId . "-" . $userId . "*";
    $fileInfo = glob($fileName);

    $fileExt = explode(".", $fileInfo[0]);
    $fileActualExt = $fileExt[1];

    $file = "../uploads/ad/adImage-" . $ImageId . "-" . $adId . "-" . $userId . "." . $fileActualExt;

    array_map('unlink', glob($fileName));

    $sql = "UPDATE adimage SET adimagestatus=1 WHERE adimageid='$ImageId';";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    exit();
 }
}
```

**Can someone please help me with a solution?**

Comment: By redirecting, you do mean it's changing the URL of the page you're on? What is `#image-remove-btn-1`, a link?

Comment: `#image-remove-btn-1` is the ID of the button. It's in the `type=button` format

Comment: Is there any `href` on button ?

Comment: Well there's nothing in the code you posted that would redirect or refresh, so this must come from somewhere else.

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: Your PHP code and ajax call back looks fine, the problem might be in your HTML only. If you are using a button click e.preventDefault(); can't do anything. Better to update your question with the HTML including the button.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed I updated the question with the `html`

Comment: A `<button>` is now favored over n `<input type="button" />` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button

Although an `<input type="button" />` should work, can you try replacing the tag with a `<button>`?

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed I changed it to type `button` but still it refreshes

Comment: @JananathJayarathna Check network tab in Chrome DevTools , where and how many request are sent.

Comment: Okay, what about the `<label>` that's enclosing the `<button>` but has a `for=file1`. `<label>` can also be used as a trigger for an `<input id='file1' type=button />`

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed that targets an input type='file'

Comment: @Nimish how do I do that?

Comment: `ctrl+shift+I` in chrome and navigate to `network` tab. Clear all requests for testing. Check `Preserve log`. Then click button you created in html.

Comment: @Nimish How to clear requests? And how can I check precisely what is happening after I click the button? Like hundreds of changes are happening when I click it

Comment: Hover over every icon you will see tooltip `clear` . You have to check each request what is happening with your code.

Comment: @Nimish only one request is going

Comment: Try keeping the button outside the label.

Comment: Can you show us the <form> tag you use? I bet it has an action attached to it. When you use <button> inside a <form>, it defaults to a submit button rather than a regular button. You can fix that by specifying <button type="button">

Comment: @geekonaut i just change the browser from `chrome` to `Microsoft edge` and now it doesn't reload. Why is that? Is this something wrong with the chrome?